# CLion and ROS: fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory

Tags: clion, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having trouble using ROS Kinetic and CLion, specifically that CLion complains the following when trying to build.

`fatal error: ros/ros.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.`

I saw the question https://answers.ros.org/question/237494/fatal-error-rosrosh-no-such-file-or-directory/, but the answers did not help me.

When I build from commandline using `catkin build`, everything builds successfully. I presume that CLion does not get the ROS environment variables, since it is the exact same error whether I source or not. I have looked at many tutorials and help pages, but none could solve the problem for me. I have tried the following:

1 Building from command line, sourcing and then launching CLion from same terminal

```
catkin build
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source devel/setup.bash
cd clion_dir/bin
./clion.sh
```

2 Adding `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash` to the following files

```
~/.bashrc
/etc/profile
~/.profile
```

3 Changing the `Exec` part of `~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-clion.desktop`

```
Exec=bash -i -c "~/applications/clion-2017.3.3/bin/clion.sh" %f
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(example)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package()

include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(listener2 src/listener2.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener2 ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282746/clion-and-ros:-fatal-error:-ros/ros.h:-no-such-file-or-directory/) by [sonjabrits](https://answers.ros.org/users/33548/sonjabrits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-02-14**:
I think CLion doesn't know how to compile your workspace when using catkin build instead of catkin_make. Try `catkin_init_workspace` in your workspace/src directory and load the created CMakeLists.txt with CLion. You can still build the package with `catkin build` command from terminal.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-02-14**:
Or at least this is how I do it with my workspaces built using `catkin build` command.

**Comment by [sonjabrits](https://answers.ros.org/users/33548/sonjabrits/) on 2018-02-14**:
That was exactly the problem! I did `catkin_init_workspace` in the `src` directory and after that it worked perfectly. Thanks so much. If you post as answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try `catkin_init_workspace` in your workspace/src directory and load the created `CMakeLists.txt` with CLion. You can still build the package with `catkin build` command from terminal.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1